# Adjective for a topic which gives rise to debate or heated discussion

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm writing a speech on sexism, as it is a topic which quite often gives rise to disputes and heated discussions; is there an adjective to describe such a topic which does so?

Comment: Impassioned.......?

Comment: Informally, you might call that a *hot button* issue.

Comment: Or just a _hot potato_. But admittedly, I've never seen this compound used attributively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ***controversial***.

Per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/controversial):

> **controversial** *adjective*
>
> : relating to or causing much discussion, disagreement, or argument
> : likely to produce controversy
>
> Examples of Controversial
>
> - Abortion is a highly controversial subject.
> - a decision that remains controversial
> - He is a controversial author.

Some other alternatives would be:

- *contentious*
- *disputed*/*disputable*
- *polemical*

Comment: Going with 'polemical.' The most appropriate for my purposes in terms of definition, and it fits in phonetically with the rest of my text.

Answer (score 1):

[Controversial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/controversIal):can convey the idea of an issue or  argument,  especially one concerning a matter about which there is strong disagreement and especially one carried on in public or in the press.

> - Of, producing, or marked by controversy: a controversial movie; a controversial stand on human rights.

Source:www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

*Contentious* is probably what you're looking for:

> con·ten·tious  adjective \kən-ˈten(t)-shəs\
>   : likely to cause people to argue or disagree
>   : involving a lot of arguing
>   : likely or willing to argue

[Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contentious)

Answer (score 0):

Incendiary:

(from GoogleSearch who appears to use the Oxford US English dictionary)

in·cen·di·ar·y

inˈsendēˌerē

adjective
adjective: incendiary

2. tending to stir up conflict.
   "incendiary rhetoric"
   synonyms:   inflammatory, rabble-rousing, provocative, seditious, subversive

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please cite your references and include a link if available; you may consult the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for further guidance on the particularities of participation here.